# Time Remaining in Process

Tags: vb.net

I've looked at other posts about this, but I must be missing something.  The time remaining isn't right and I'm a bit stuck on this.  TIA

```
mTimeSpan = Now - mStartTime
If (mThisRec > 10) Then
    txt_StatusBox.Text = txt_StatusBox.Text & "Time remaining about "
    Dim mRate As Double = (CDec(mThisRec) / CDec(mTimeSpan.TotalSeconds)) * (CDec(mMaxRecs) - CDec(mThisRec)) / 1000

mTimeSpan = Now.AddSeconds(mRate) - Now
If mTimeSpan.Hours > 0 Then
    If mTimeSpan.Hours > 0 Then
        txt_StatusBox.Text = txt_StatusBox.Text & mTimeSpan.Hours.ToString & " hours, "
    End If
    If mTimeSpan.Minutes > 0 Then
        txt_StatusBox.Text = txt_StatusBox.Text & mTimeSpan.Minutes.ToString & " minutes."
    Else
        txt_StatusBox.Text = txt_StatusBox.Text & mTimeSpan.Seconds.ToString & " seconds."
    End If
End If
```

Comment: What isn't right about it? I *suspect* that the *first* `If mTimeSpan.Hours > 0 Then` should be `If mTimeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero Then`.

Comment: Where is the End If for the first If block?

Comment: How about explaining how it isn't right? And how it differs from expectations.

Comment: Sorry for the missing End If.  There is a ton of code that follows that doesn't contribute to the problem.

I will try the TimeSSpan.Zero suggestion.

What it is doing is showing 5 minutes remaining on a 54,000 input file that is only 100 records in and that took 10 seconds to process.  It takes it MUCH longer than five minutes to finish the file.

Comment: Ran another test of the code today on a laptop with a SQL server back-end and when it started it said 42 minutes for completion.  It ran in less than 18 minutes.  Why the error in determining the runtime?

Comment: And on a slower machine it stated that it would process the 52K records in 7 minutes.  after 10 and a half minutes only 5000 had been processed.  Anyone have any ideas?